# Javascript Alert issue

Tags: javascript

I am having some problem regarding a Alert box.

My site is performing a Session out and after logging out it goes to the index/main.html.

Currently, I am showing a Pop up alert once the session times out and Redirecting it to the Index page.

I want to show a Alert message once the session times out in the Index page saying: "Your session has time out, plz Login to continue'- If the user clicks 'Ok' he will be able to Login again.

Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of `alert`, you can use a `confirm`. Then he has a chance :).

Comment: If you want to give ok and cancel options then use confirm instead of Alert.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you redirect to the login page when ok is clicked ?

like so:

```
   document.location.href = "...login page...";
```

Comment: Just posted the 'Code' which is doing this Session time out and Redirecting it to the Login page.
I am able to show the 'Alert' message while the session times out, but want to show the Alert message once the session times out and goes into the Login page.